# I have used a vector to create a list of class objects. How can I call the constructor with parameters when I initialize the vector?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, parameter-passing

I have a class Random. The constructor has a parameter "int range" if I say

```
class Random
{
private: 
int r; 

public:
 Random(int range)
  {
     r = range
  }
}
```

I want to create a vector of objects of class Random. How do i pass the range parameter in that case

```
vector<Random> v;
```

Where does the parameter go?  Bit confused.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are asking about?  Describing code in English can be very ambiguous.

Comment: You may be looking for the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 2):

There's no great way to do what you want.

Since `Random` is cheap to copy, you can do this:

```
vector<Random> v{Random(1), Random(2), Random(3)};
```

but if it wasn't cheap to copy (or not copyable at all), then you would do this instead:

```
vector<Random> v;
v.reserve(3);
v.emplace_back(1);
v.emplace_back(2);
v.emplace_back(3);
```